# Injector provided to template via ngTemplateOutletInjector doesn't seem to be the same one accessed by template components

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a service which controls modal creation.  Below is the code in that service which initiates modal creation, using property injection to supply the component instance with a reference to a new injector

```
  open(type: ModalType, template: TemplateRef<any>, model?: any) {
    let ref = this.modal.open(ModalContainerComponent);
    let component = ref.componentInstance as ModalContainerComponent;
    component.tRef = template;
    component.injector = Injector.create({
      providers: [
        { provide: NgForm,
          useFactory: () => {
            return component.form;
          }
        }
      ]
    });
  }
```

The `NgForm` instance that is provided here is retrieved from the component instance as a `ViewChild` because the modal service needs it elsewhere.

The modal component (component instance) has the following template:

```
<form
  #form="ngForm"
  (ngSubmit)="commit()"
  [ngFormOptions]="{ updateOn: 'change' }">
  <ng-container *ngIf="initialized && tRef && m && injector">
    <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="tRef; context: { $implicit: { m } }"
      [ngTemplateOutletInjector]="injector"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

The portion containing the template outlet is conditionally rendered after view initialization, and by the time an NgForm is requested by anything in the sub-template, it should be available to the factory provider in the injector created by the modal service.  Unfortunately, components in that template seem to be receiving a different injector than the one provided via `ngTemplateOutletInjector` as above.  The one they receive does not provide the reference to `NgForm`.  This results in the following error:

> NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm

I've verified that within the provider the `NgForm` instance is available.  I'm sure I must be missing something but as `ngTemplateOutletInjector` is a new feature with little documentation it's a little unclear to me.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this a little bit eventually I received a parser error for the modal component's template where the template ref is passed to the template outlet:

> Parser Error: Binding expression cannot contain chained expression at column 7 in [tRef; context: { $implicit: { m } }]

`ngTemplateOutletInjector` is really the third input parameter of the `ngTemplateOutlet` directive. Explicitly binding to all three inputs separately as follows solved the aforementioned error, and also the original problem:

```
<ng-container
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="tRef"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: { m } }"
  [ngTemplateOutletInjector]="injector"></ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

An adjacent answer to the above to note that you can provide all three input parameters via the expression as follows:

```
  <ng-container
      *ngTemplateOutlet="tRef; context: { $implicit: { m } }; injector: injector"
      ></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```